# How to disable keyboard in particular segement of UISegementedControl?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uisegmentedcontrol

I have three segments in UISegementedControl. Segment 1 is having a UITextfield. When switching between these segments, I want to disable the keyboard in the remaining two of them. (Segment 0 and Segment 2)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `view.endEditing(true)` will resolve the problem.
In my scenario, I considered a subview of each segmented view.
`subview.endEditing(true)`. So keyboard will automatically disappear when switching between Segments.

```
@IBAction func indexChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
   for subview in self.view.subviews {
      if (subview.tag == 2 || subview.tag == 0) {
           subview.endEditing(true)
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: This is an answer.